# Rails: Query n IDs before and after some ID

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like to query n users before and after some user.

**Edit:** for clarity

```
def local_query(id, range)
  local_min = id - range*0.5
  local_max = id + range*0.5
  local_users = User.where(id: [local_min..local_max])
  return local_users
end
```

Comment: I *think* I understand what you're asking, but could you provide a specific example with a couple sample rows of data and how you'd like for it to look?

Comment: May be following things may help you, User.find(:all, limit: '10, 10000000000') And User.find(:all, limit: 10, offset: 10) also you can add `order` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing that you want to query user by limiting ID(specific range of ID) i think following should work

```
user_id_min_range = 5
user_id_max_range = 10
User.where(id: (user_id_min_range..user_id_max_range))
```

Above code will return users whose ID are between 6-10

Or you can also do like following

```
User.where("id > ?", 5).order(id: :asc).limit(5)
```

Above query will select users with id greater than 5 and order them in Ascending ID and return top 5 users.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you could use this scopes:

```
scope :next_users, ->(start_id, user_limit) {
  order(id: :asc).where("id > ?", start_id).limit(user_limit)
}

scope :before_users, ->(start_id, user_limit) {
  order(id: :desc).where("id < ?", start_id).limit(user_limit)
}
```

They will select n of the next or before users for a predefined user id.